# Как можно добавить секунды к записям Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как можно добавить секунды к записям Wordpress? Чтобы можно было указывать дату и время публикации записи с секундами, но и естественно чтобы можно было управлять секундами из админки. Подскажите пожалуйста идеи, или возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В базе время сохраняется в формате datetime, с секундами.

Вывести время поста с секундами несложно, надо использовать формат времени с секундами в функциях `get_post_time()` или `the_time()`.

В админке секунды тоже выводятся, в

```
<input type="hidden" id="ss" name="ss" value="49">
```

Надо с помощью своего js убрать атрибут hidden у этого поля ввода и отформатировать его с через css.